# How to use react with yarn 3?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg, yarn-v2

I tried using `CRA` and also `vite` for creating new react app. I have yarn 3.3.0 installed on my machine. Now after running yarn install command, it installs package dependencies inside `.yarn` folder and no `node_module` gets created. As per my understanding about yarn 3.x, they have space optimized this approach in order to avoid unwanted duplicate package installation per project and I'm pretty much convinced with that approach.
But due to this, my react application is unable to resolve any of the dependencies in my application including `react` itself.
I searched for possible solutions on google and stack overflow and got a suggestion to create `.yarnrc.yml` file with following content

`nodeLinker: node-modules`

When I create this file and run `yarn install` command, it again creates `node_modules` folder. And error goes away.
I wanted to know if that's the right approach to use yarn 3 with react? Because with this approach, I'm again going ahead with npm based approach of dependency resolution. So As per my understanding I'm again degrading the performance of yarn 3.
Please suggest.